# How to store ACE editor with themes and extentions in a single file?

Tags: javascript, editor, ace-editor

I try to store all stuff of [the ace editor](http://ace.c9.io) in a single file, e.g. themes, modes and extensions. Therefore I downloaded the ace-master-build package from GitHub and concatenated the files. That did not work (many errors in the console).
So I cloned the whole [repository from GitHub](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace) and tried to use the `Makefile.dryice.js` to put it in a single file automatically:

```
$ ./Makefile.dryice.js --s --m --nc --target ../test
```

That did what I want, but after I integrated it in my website it logs:
Ace is not defined.

So what can I do? Is it even possible to use ACE in a single file?

Cheers, Marco

Comment: any insights since asking this question?

Comment: @tomer34 I eventually managed to get ace in a single file, but don't know exactly how I did it. It is used in my "little" file manager: https://github.com/misterunknown/ifm
If you have the same issues I maybe can help you when you provide the error message you get.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get what you want but you can load ace from a single script tag: `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.4.12/ace.js" integrity="sha512-GZ1RIgZaSc8rnco/8CXfRdCpDxRCphenIiZ2ztLy3XQfCbQUSCuk8IudvNHxkRA3oUg6q0qejgN/qqyG1duv5Q==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>`
and load everything else using [Require](https://requirejs.org/) . I done a similar project in which I had to compress the whole file and this helped.

Cheers, Adhvaith.